# Solving $CT = PC$ for transforms in $SE(3)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations, rigid-transformation

I have three transforms: $C$, $T$, and $P$. Each of these transforms consists of 3D rotations and translations. I know $T$ and $P$, and I would like to solve for $C$. They are related by $T = C^{-1} P C$. Is there a good way to solve this? Is this even guaranteed to have a solution?

The only way I can think of solving it is to express the equation in the element-wise form, and solve the $16$ equations for the various components of $C$. Besides being painful, this would be error-prone, and I'm hoping that there is a cleaner solution.

Comment: Does $C$ need to be invertible, or would you like any solution to $CT = PC$?

Comment: Wait, do you mean that $C$ $T$ and $P$ are all rigid transformations?

Comment: Yeah, C, T, and P are all rigid transformations. I'll update the question to make it more clear, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming all three are rigid transformations:

If such a $C$ exists, then $T$ and $P$ are said to be [orthogonally similar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_similarity).  In fact, given that $T$ and $P$ are rigid transformations, we know that the following are equivalent:

- $T$ and $P$ are orthogonally similar
- $T$ and $P$ are similar
- $T$ and $P$ are rotations by the same angle

If $T$ and $P$ are similar, we can find a similarity through the [(real) spectral decompositions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_theorem):

Suppose $C_1,C_2$ are unitary matrices (rigid transformations) such that
$$
C_1TC_1^{-1} = R\\
C_2 P C_2^{-1} = R
$$
where $R$ is the corresponding rotation around the $z$-axis. We then have
$$
T = C_1^{-1} C_2 R C_2^{-1} C_1 = (C_2^{-1}C_1)^{-1} R (C_2^{-1}C_1)
$$

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite understand what you mean by "the corresponding rotation around the Z-axis". Also, given R, I'm still unclear about how to get $C_1$ and $C_2$.

Comment: Also, must $T$ and $P$ be pure rotations with zero translation for $C$ to exist?

Comment: Sorry, I thought you meant linear transformations rather than affine, so that translations would be disallowed. Do you know how to diagonalize a matrix? this process is parallel.

Comment: I'll update this to include translations if I have the time.

Comment: Sorry, I was under the impression that "proper rigid transforms" implies "rotations and translations". I was representing the transforms as homogeneous 4x4 matrices.

Comment: Terminology varies between fields. Not your fault. I understand what you mean now.

Answer (score 0):

### The solution in other words

$C$ is rigid transformations therefore: $C^{-1}=C^T$
and

\begin{equation}
(1)  T=C^TPC
\end{equation}

Use orthogonal decomposition for T and P:
 (According to (1) $T$ and $P$ have the same eigenvalues so diagonal matrix will be the same)

\begin{equation}
P = U_p^TDU_p
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
T = U_t^TDU_t
\end{equation}

(Note that this is not a standart SVD decomposition)
where $U_p, U_t$ is orthogonal in $D$ is diagonal matrix
And and according to (1)
$U_t^TDU_t=C^TU_p^TDU_pC$
Therefore:
$U_t=U_pC$
And $C$ can be obtained:
$C=U_p^TU_t$